# GraphQL Queries using different server on client side

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, create-react-app, react-apollo

I have a Create-React-App server that proxies all API requests to my back-end Express-GraphQL server, located at localhost:3001

Whenever I make a request on the homepage component '/' it sends the request to "localhost:3000/graphql' which works just fine. But if I make a request on a nested child component that sends the request to something like

```
"localhost:3000/topic/:id"
```

it sends back a 404 because it can't find "http://localhost:3000/topic/graphql"

So my question is, how do I tell React to still make those requests to localhost:3000/graphql for nested child components?

Comment: Can you post the code that sets up the routing, and where the requests are made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For react-apollo, when you're creating a new ApolloClient, set the uri to `/graphql`

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
    uri: "/graphql", // you might have missed the `/` at the beginning
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes I had setup the networkInterface without the / in front of graphql. Thank you!